# Pandas group to others

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a question about the syntax for grouping "other".  For example,

df

```
Type  Start  End Count Total
A     x      a   1     3
A     x      b   1     3
A     x      c   1     3
A     y      A   2     4
A     y      b   1     4
A     y      c   1     4
B     x      A   1     6
B     x      b   2     6
B     x      c   3     6
B     y      a   3     6
B     y      b   2     6
B     y      c   1     6
```

Group by Type/Start/End columns, if End doesn't contain "a" or "A" then label them as "other"

```
Type  Start  End   Count Total
A     x      a     1     3
A     x      other 2     3
A     y      A     2     4
A     y      other 2     4
B     x      A     1     6
B     x      other 5     6
B     y      a     3     6
B     y      other 3     6
```

Comment: @Grr I did df.groupby(['Type','Start','End'']).agg({'Count':'sum','Total':'mean'}) but I don't know how to do the "other"

Comment: Please consider accepting one of these answers as well, if your problem was solved ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oops sorry I forgot.  Will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. The first two parameters to `groupby` are fine, but the last needs modification.

```
f = {'Count': 'sum', 'Total' : 'mean'}   
v = df.End.where(df.End.isin(['a', 'A']), 'other')

df.groupby(['Type', 'Start', v]).agg(f).reset_index()

  Type Start    End  Total  Count
0    A     x      a      3      1
1    A     x  other      3      2
2    A     y      A      4      2
3    A     y  other      4      2
4    B     x      A      6      1
5    B     x  other      6      5
6    B     y      a      6      3
7    B     y  other      6      3
```

---

**Details**

Use `where`/`mask` to alter `df.End`'s values accordingly;

```
v = df.End.where(df.End.isin(['a', 'A']), 'other')
```

Or,

```
v = df.End.mask(~df.End.isin(['a', 'A']), 'other')
```

```
v

0         a
1     other
2     other
3         A
4     other
5     other
6         A
7     other
8     other
9         a
10    other
11    other
Name: End, dtype: object
```

Alternatively, lowercase the column and compare.

```
v = df.End.where(df.End.str.lower().eq('a'), 'other')
```

The rest, as they say, is history. If you're interested in preserving column order, slap on a `reindex` call at the end.

```
df.groupby(['Type', 'Start', v])\
  .agg(f)\
  .reset_index()\
  .reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist())

  Type Start    End  Count  Total
0    A     x      a      1      3
1    A     x  other      2      3
2    A     y      A      2      4
3    A     y  other      2      4
4    B     x      A      1      6
5    B     x  other      5      6
6    B     y      a      3      6
7    B     y  other      3      6
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need replace all values not contains `a` and `A` to `other` by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) and condition by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then use `groupby` by columns and Series `s`:

```
s = df['End'].where(df['End'].isin(['a','A']), 'other')
print (s)
0         a
1     other
2     other
3         A
4     other
5     other
6         A
7     other
8     other
9         a
10    other
11    other
Name: End, dtype: object    

df = (df.groupby(['Type', 'Start', s])
        .agg({'Count':'sum', 'Total':'mean'})
        .reset_index())
```

Another similar solution is replace column `End` and use your original solution for `groupby` + `agg`:

```
df['End'] = np.where(df['End'].isin(['a','A']), df['End'], 'other')
#alternatively
#df['End'] = df['End'].where(df['End'].isin(['a','A']), 'other')
df = (df.groupby(['Type', 'Start', 'End'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'Count':'sum', 'Total':'mean'}))

print (df)
  Type Start    End  Count  Total
0    A     x      a      1      3
1    A     x  other      2      3
2    A     y      A      2      4
3    A     y  other      2      4
4    B     x      A      1      6
5    B     x  other      5      6
6    B     y      a      3      6
7    B     y  other      3      6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value of the entries in `End` to reflect your desired change and use `groupby` as you already described.

```
df.loc[~df.End.isin(['A', 'a']), 'End'] = 'other'
df.groupby(['Type','Start','End'']).agg({'Count':'sum','Tota‌​l':'mean'})
```